# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_2/convolution'

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

I got this error message when declaring the input layer in Keras.

> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for
>   'conv2d_2/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,28,28],
>   [3,3,28,32].

My code is like this

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,28,28)))
```

Sample application: https://github.com/IntellijSys/tensorflow/blob/master/Keras.ipynb

Comment: I think you want to use a 3x3 kernel. In this case you should write `(3, 3)` instead of `3, 3`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

By default, Convolution2D (https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) expects the input to be in the format (samples, rows, cols, channels), which is "channels-last". Your data seems to be in the format (samples, channels, rows, cols). You should be able to fix this using the optional keyword `data_format = 'channels_first'` when declaring the Convolution2D layer.

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1,28,28), data_format='channels_first'))
```

Comment: Note that it can be set globally in ~/.keras/keras.json:     "image_data_format": "channels_first"

Answer (score 41):

I had the same problem, however the solution provided in this thread did not help me.
In my case it was a different problem that caused this error:

---

### Code

```
imageSize=32
classifier=Sequential() 

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape = (imageSize, imageSize, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu')) 
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu')) 
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu')) 
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())
```

---

### Error

The image size is 32 by 32. After the first convolutional layer, we reduced it to 30 by 30. (If I understood convolution correctly)

Then the pooling layer divides it, so 15 by 15.

Then another convolutional layer reduces it to 13 by 13...

I hope you can see where this is going:
In the end, my **feature map is so small that my pooling layer (or convolution layer) is too big to go over it** - and that causes the error

---

### Solution

The easy solution to this error is to either make the image size bigger or use less convolutional or pooling layers.

Comment: Great intuitive explanation. However, one thing I don't get from your answer is why the reduction from 32x32 to 30x30 after the convolution layer. The division of pixels / pool_size ("window" size) is obvious and can't understand how I did not figured that out myself. The output of convolution layer is: IMG_HEIGHT - kernel_size + 1.

Comment: Its been a long time since ive done this, so bear with me: If e.g. your base is 4x4, and your convolution layer is 3x3. Try drawing the different positions you can put your conv layer on top of the 4x4 base layer. There are 4 positions if im right. So your output of this operations are a 2x2 new layer. In other words, the convolution operation decreased the size of the base layer. A similar thing happens in my above example.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/L5qTXTfP/image.jpg

Answer (score 5):

Keras is available with following backend compatibility:

TensorFlow : By google, 
Theano : Developed by LISA lab,
CNTK : By Microsoft

Whenever you see a error with [?,X,X,X], [X,Y,Z,X], its a channel issue to fix this use auto mode of Keras:

Import

```
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```

"tf" format means that the convolutional kernels will have the shape (rows, cols, input_depth, depth)

This will always work ...

Comment: This answer let me to the solution on my own environment but seems that a few things have been renamed in later versions of Keras: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12649

Answer (score 0):

You can instead preserve spatial dimensions of the volume such that the output volume size matches the input volume size, by setting the value to “same”.
use padding='same'

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
from keras import backend
backend.set_image_data_format('channels_last')
```

Depending on your preference, you can use `'channels_first'` or `'channels_last'` to set the image data format. ([Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/set_image_data_format))

If this does not work and your image size is small, try reducing the architecture of your CNN, as previous posters mentioned.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
    # define the model as a class
class LeNet:

  '''
      In a sequential model, we stack layers sequentially. 
      So, each layer has unique input and output, and those inputs and outputs 
      then also come with a unique input shape and output shape.

  '''

  @staticmethod                ## class can instantiated only once 
  def init(numChannels, imgRows, imgCols , numClasses, weightsPath=None):

    # if we are using channel first we have update the input size
    if backend.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
      inputShape = (numChannels , imgRows , imgCols)
    else: 
      inputShape = (imgRows , imgCols , numChannels)

    # initilize the model
    model = models.Sequential()

    # Define the first set of CONV => ACTIVATION => POOL LAYERS

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(  filters=6,kernel_size=(5,5),strides=(1,1), 
                              padding="valid",activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_uniform',input_shape=inputShape))
    model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
```

I hope it would help :)

See code : [Fashion_Mnist_Using_LeNet_CNN](https://github.com/hritik5102/Fundamentals_of_DS_ML_DL/blob/master/Deep_learning_for_computer_vision/02-Fashion_Mnist_Using_LeNet_CNN/FashionMnist_Classification_Using_LeNet.ipynb)