# ValueError: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv2d

Tags: keras, model, valueerror, grayscale

l'm trying to making a model for grayscale images.
It looks like there is a problem with the output shape and l tried to add a padding to the conv2d put it gives me the error of an input shape in the testing.
[the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQhd4.png)

with implementation:

```
model=keras.Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(48, 48), activation='relu', input_shape=(105,105,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(24, 24), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (24,24), strides = (2,2), activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, (12,12), strides = (2,2), activation = 'relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(12, 12), activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(12, 12), activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(12, 12), activation='relu'))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(

Dense(4096,activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(2383,activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
```

the error:

```
ValueError: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv2d_9. Consider increasing the input size. Received input shape [None, 105, 105, 1] which would produce output shape with a zero or negative value in a dimension.
```

Answer (score 4):

A little late but if you use padding = 'same' it should work as well:

```py
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(48, 48), activation='relu', input_shape=(105,105,1), padding='same'))
```

This basically keeps the output size the same as the input size.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is with substracting the kernel size of (48,48) from (1, 105,105). Try to change the input from (105, 105, 1) to (1, 105,105) using **data_format**:

`model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(48, 48), activation='relu', input_shape=(105,105,1), data_format='channels_first')))`

You can read about it here:
[Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_2/convolution'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645276/negative-dimension-size-caused-by-subtracting-3-from-1-for-conv2d-2-convolution/45647715#45647715)

Answer (score 0):

for my 1-D CNN training, adding " padding='same' " worked for me as well.